# Alphabetical Sorting Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I used following function for sorting array.

```
var trArr = [{'Abc', 1}, {'ACd', 3}, {'Aab', 4}];

function compare(a,b) {
          if (a.name > b.name)
          {
              return -1;
          }
          if (a.name < b.name)
          {
              return 1;
          }

          return 0;
}

trArr.sort(compare);
```

result:

```
[{'ACd', 3}, {'Aab', 4}, {'Abc', 1}];
```

above result is due to capital 'C'

I need the following result:

```
[{'Aab', 4}, {'Abc', 1}, {'ACd', 3}];
```

Comment: `.name.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var trArr = [{
    name: 'Abc',
    id: 1
}, {
    name: 'ACd',
    id: 3
}, {
    name: 'Aab',
    id: 4
}];

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

trArr.sort(compare);
console.log(trArr)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ta3nC/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toLowerCase`

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```